# Placing grid contents in the center

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
.skills{
    display: grid;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    place-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        'one1'
        'two2'
        'three3'
        'four4'
        'five5'
    ;
}
.skillz:nth-child(1){
    grid-area: one1;
}
.skillz:nth-child(2){
    grid-area: two2;
}
.skillz:nth-child(3){
    grid-area: three3;
}
.skillz:nth-child(4){
    grid-area: four4;
}
.skillz:nth-child(5){
    grid-area: five5;
}
.content-head_links{
    display: none;
}
.skillz{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    transition: 250ms;
}
.skillz:hover{
    transform: translateY(5px);
}
.Top-skills{
    width: min(95%, 70rem);
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
    .skills{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: min(95%, 70rem);
        gap: 20px;
        max-width: 400px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        place-content: center;
        grid-template-areas: 
        'one1 two2'
        'three3 four4'
        'five5 .'
        ;
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="Top-skills">
    <div class="skills">
                
        <div class="skillz html">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>html</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz css">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>css</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz scss">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>scss</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz javascript">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>javascript</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz React">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>React</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to make the grid contents center on the webpage and each of the child element have the same size, But whenever I try to center it using place content or margin:0 auto; It doesn't work, In 768px the size of the grid contents become smaller in size.
I want the grid contents to be center and also have equal reasonable size on smaller screens and when it reaches 768px.
P.S I'm working with mobile first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will be useful for you to learn about grid layouts in css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

In here, as I understood you problem, you want to center your skill cards one card in one row.

In grid layout there are two properties called,

1. grid-template-columns - specifies the number of coulmns in a grid(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows)
2. grid-template-rows - specifies number of rows in a grid(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

Here, if you want to keep all the cards in one row, you have to use the `grid-template-columns` property. And If you want to keep one card at a row, you need to use the `grid-template-rows property`.

Another thing is when you use `grid-template-areas`, we have to define the areas that we want to locate a single row, inside the one `''` . You can refer this to find more details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas

In your code you can try like below.

```css
.skills{
    display: grid;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    width: 50%;
    align-content: center;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'one1' 'two2' 'three3' 'four4' 'five5';
}
.skillz:nth-child(1){
    grid-area: one1;
}
.skillz:nth-child(2){
    grid-area: two2;
}
.skillz:nth-child(3){
    grid-area: three3;
}
.skillz:nth-child(4){
    grid-area: four4;
}
.skillz:nth-child(5){
    grid-area: five5;
}
.content-head_links{
    display: none;
}
.skillz{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 22px -1px rgba(202,202,202,0.75);
    transition: 250ms;
}
.skillz:hover{
    transform: translateY(5px);
}
.Top-skills{
    width: min(95%, 70rem);
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
    .skills{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: min(95%, 70rem);
        gap: 20px;
        max-width: 400px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        place-content: center;
        grid-template-areas: 
        'one1 two2'
        'three3 four4'
        'five5 .'
        ;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Top-skills">
    <div class="skills">
                
        <div class="skillz html">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>html</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz css">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>css</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz scss">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>scss</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz javascript">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>javascript</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>
        <div class="skillz React">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <h3>React</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam exercitationem </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```